# Is there an HTML optimizing command I can access in Ubuntu's bash shell?

Tags: bash

I have a bash shell script that I use to upload a set of HTML files to a web server. The script makes various changes to the code before it uploads it.

One thing I'd like to do is strip the HTML code of comments and excess white space.

Is there a command I can use to do that within the bash script?

Comment: In case you don't get the answer here because it isn't strictly Ubuntu-related, you may consider asking over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `tidy`. It might help you achieve the results you'd like to have. Version 20091223cvs-1 is available from the repositories.

Tidy is a:

> HTML syntax checker and reformatter Corrects markup in a way compliant
>   with the latest standards, and optimal for the popular browsers. [...]

Homepage: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This is a viable solution so I marked it correct, but actually, I ended up using HTMLcompressor instead: http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/ . Answer was found on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1388596/184108

Comment: Thank you for following through! That tool will probably better suit to your needs. Also the compressor's page is a very interesting read.